# How to allow AWS user to start instances only in one VPC by ID or TAG?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have multiple VPCs, one for each environment. I want that a user in Dev group should only be able to launch instances in that one VPC. Similarly for other environments as well. How to accomplish this ? Right now, I can restrict user to not be able to stop, start instances based on Tag (Environment=Dev).

Is it possible to have such a policy, that would allow to launch an Instance only in a particular VPC or a VPC with a particular tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "Developers" like IAM group and have this permission in it:

```
{
"Version": "2014-11-28",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::subnet/subnet-00000000",
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::instance/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::image/ami-*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::key-pair/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:< region >::security-group/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Then this is sufficient to issue from AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --key-name yourkey --image-id ami-00000000 --security-group-ids sg-00000000 --instance-type t2.micro --subnet-id subnet-00000000
```

Don't forget to replace region, account number,key name, AMI, security group id, instance type, subnet ID.

Comment: I had this policy and it allows users to launch instance in one VPC. However what I also wanted was some ability to restrict users to start, stop, terminate instances only one particular VPC, which as it stands is not possible using IAM. Resource level permissions which include VPC-ID based filtering is not yet supported for desired actions.

Answer (score 0):

You then can add this:

```
{
  "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissionsWithInstancesAndTags",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
    "ec2:StopInstances",
    "ec2:StartInstances"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNTID:instance/*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "ec2:ResourceTag/yourTAG": "yourVALUE"
    }
  }
}
```

Even though  these are EC2 tags rather than VPC, it will still work perfectly if you tag the ones you want or launch with a tag to begin with.